# Does Stepper provide an event handling for step changes?

Tags: angular

I am using mat-stepper for my project and in side mat-stepper i have mat-Datatable.
in every step i have to hide and show different columns so i want to send some data to every step changes is this possible?

I was thinking if stepper provide some kind of event handling for this purpose.

Thank you in Advance.

**Edited**

stepper.ts

```
  onSelectionChange(e: any){
    this.selectedIndex = e.selectedIndex;
  }
```

stepper.html

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"  labelPosition="bottom"  #stepper>
<mat-step>
  <ng-template matStepLabel>DataTable</ng-template>
  <app-data-table [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex"></app-data-table>
</mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

datatable.ts

```
  @Input() selectedIndex: any;
  show: boolean = false;
  if (this.selectedIndex != 3) 
   {this.show = true;}
```

datatable.html

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [hidden]="!show">Delete</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [hidden]="!show">
          <button><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
      </td>
   </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :  selectionChange() event (Event emitted when the selected step has changed.)
example code of using :

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper 
(selectionChange)="onStepChange($event)">


onStepChange(event: any): void {
    //use event.selectedIndex to know which step your user in.
}
```

you can read more here: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: i tried this way but sometimes its just not checking selectedIndex.for example in following code.it does not get inside if. when its is in step 2.
`if (this.selectedIndex != 3) {
        this.show = true;
      } `

Comment: Can you paste the full code ? youre using this.selectedIndex while you need to use event.selectedIndex

Comment: i soved the issue using service. thank you